# VectorDrawableCompat StackOverflowError on Android pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-vectordrawable

According to analytics we have set up, we are getting a StackOverflowError in VectorDrawableCompat only on certain android hardware. All cases have happened pre-Lollipop so far (4.4.2 and 4.4.4). Normally I would assume something we are doing incorrectly would cause a StackOverflowError, but I have been unable to replicate it so far on newer devices. Analytics are also showing that in all cases, users have extremely low memory, although that would probably be caused by the StackOverflowError.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
   at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.<init>(Bitmap.java:120)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Bitmap.java)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:786)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:753)
   at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VectorDrawableCompatState.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1028)
   at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.draw(VectorDrawableCompat.java:361)
   at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:70)
   at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1037)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14740)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
   at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.draw(NestedScrollView.java:1768)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2961)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2443)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1223)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2443)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1223)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1223)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13631)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14457)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3117)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14743)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13636)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13678)
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2401)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2273)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1903)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1020)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5762)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

There is a Chris Banes blog post where he talks about avoiding certain animation things pre-Lollipop. But I do not believe we are doing any of those things (Path Morphing, Path Interpolation, Move along path).

[Chris Banes post](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Has anyone else ever ran into this issue? If so, how have you solved it? Thanks.